# Spring метод findByUsername возвращает Optional.empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, аутентификация, spring-data-jpa

Делаю CRUD приложение на Spring Boot с Spring Security и Spring Data JPA стартерами. Сделал регистрацию пользователя, пытаюсь сделать аутентификацию, но при попытке залогиниться метод `findByUsername` в `PersonRepository` почему-то возвращает `Optional.empty`.
Сделал при помощи `System.out.println` проверки на `null` в методе `loadUserByUsername` сервиса `PersonDetailsService` - `username` передается нормально, но возвращается пустой optional.

PersonDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class PersonDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {        
        if (username != null) System.out.println("Username is " + username);
        Optional<Person> person = personRepository.findByUsername(username); 
        System.out.println("Person is " + person);
            return new PersonDetails(person.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found")));
  
    }
    
    
    public Person registerNewUserAccount(Person person) {
        person.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new Role(1L, "ROLE_USER")));
        person.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(person.getPassword()));
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
    
    public Person findById(Long Id) {
        Optional<Person> oPerson = personRepository.findById(Id); 
        return oPerson.orElse(null);    
    }
    
    public Person findByUsername(String name) {
        System.out.println("nachalo");
        Optional<Person> oPerson = personRepository.findByUsername(name);
        System.out.println(oPerson.get().getName());
        return oPerson.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
        
    }
    
}
```

PersonRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends EntityRepository<Person> {
    Optional<Person> findByUsername(String username);
    Person findByEmail(String email);
    Optional<Person> findById(Long id);
}
```

EntityRepository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface EntityRepository<E extends AbstractEntity> extends JpaRepository<E, Long> {}
```

View:

```
<div th:unless="${isUserAuth}">
    <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Войдите</legend>
            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">
                Неправильные имя или пароль.
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
            <label for="username">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
            <label for="password">Пароль</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Войти</button>
                <a th:href="@{/registration}">Регистрация</a>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Вывод в консоль при попытке залогиниться:

```
Username is user4
2023-09-08T18:23:01.528+03:00 DEBUG 10268 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.email,
        p1_0.password,
        p1_0.username 
    from
        person p1_0 
    where
        p1_0.username=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.email,
        p1_0.password,
        p1_0.username 
    from
        person p1_0 
    where
        p1_0.username=?
Person is Optional.empty
```

Хотя пользователь с таким именем user4 есть в базе данных.

UPD:
Person:

```
package com.example.demo6.entities;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Transient;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;


@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Size(min=3, message = "Не меньше 3 знаков")
    private String username;
    //@Valid
    //@Email
    private String email;
    @Size(min=5, message = "Не меньше 5 знаков")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    
    public String getName() {
        return username;
    }
    
    
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public void setName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

PersonDetails:

```
package com.example.demo6.security;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.example.demo6.entities.Person;

public class PersonDetails implements UserDetails {
    private final Person person;

    
    public PersonDetails(Person person) {
        super();
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {   
        return person.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return person.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

Comment: А приведите ещё весь код класса `Person`

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы `PersonDetails` своим методом `getUsername()` (я так понимаю, этот класс у вас реализует `UserDetails`) возвращал то, по чему вы ищите пользователя методом репозитория `findByUsername()`. А то тут может возникнуть путаница: условно, у вас фактически идентификатором служит почта, а вы в `getUsername()` возвращаете поле `username`. Ну, по крайней мере, у меня подобная ошибка (не логинился Security-юзер) была по такой причине.

Comment: Проверил: там вроде все правильно. Сейчас выложу код.

Comment: Методом исключения можно прийти к выводу, что пользователя в базе всё-таки нет. Скорее всего, в базе по ошибке случилось несколько схем, Спринг работает с одной, ты проверяешь другую.

Comment: Для проверки можно добавить в `PersonRepository` метод `findAll`  и распечатать разок, что там в базе.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, я только сейчас заметил, что у меня над `Person` имя таблицы указано как `person`, а регистрировал я эти записи когда оно было `users`, в результате у меня аккаунты не в той таблице. В общем я идиот. Сейчас попробую исправить.